# PHP multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two questions.

How can i create an array which i can add two values per index like:

`$sample[0] = ("abc",10);`

Second is that once i have created this array i would like to sort this array according to the 2nd value at the index.

So if i have an  array like:

```
$sample[0] = ("abc",32);
$sample[1] = ("def",11);
```

The sorted result should be:

```
$sample[0] = ("def",11);
$sample[1] = ("abc",32);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to part one:

```
$sample[0] = array("abc", 10);
```

Answer to part two:

```
array_multisort($sample, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Testing Environment:

```
<?php

$sample[0] = array("abc", 32);
$sample[1] = array("def", 11);
print_r($sample);

array_multisort($sample, SORT_NUMERIC);

echo '<br />';
print_r($sample);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => 32 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => def [1] => 11 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => def [1] => 11 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => 32 ) )
```

Warning from @Deceze:
    Above functionality is coincidental; correct code is:

```
usort($sample, function ($a, $b) { return $a[1] - $b[1]; })
```

Comment: I have declared my array as `$sample = array();`.

I have a while loop where `$i` is the iterator. I am unable to add something like: `$sample[$i] = ("abc",12);`

Comment: `$sample[$i] = array("abc", 12);`

Comment: Check out the answer to part two, just tested it;

Comment: `usort($sample, function ($a, $b) { return $a[1] - $b[1]; })` - this is the correct sort. I'm not sure why `array_multisort` supposedly works, but that's only coincidence if anything.

Comment: Feel free to try the above code, tested in EasyPHP Dev Server Environment

Comment: http://3v4l.org/j8eRh - it does *not* work.

Comment: Yeah I just tried it with more than the initial two also, thus referred do you

Comment: yeah @user3760741 but are you finally getting the multi-dimensional arrays right? You can't have `= (foo, bar)`, you can though; have `= [foo, bar]` since PHP5.4

Comment: @deceze your solution only is working